# Fetch request sends a lot of request background

Tags: reactjs, fetch

When used fetch function to send requests to a http endpoint then it continues sending lots of same of them. I saw  there are many requests that sent and marked as pending. Is that normal such intensive requests?

Here is my code for react.js:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchData=async()=>{
           await fetch('https://my-get-request-url')
          .then(stats => stats.json())
          .then(data => {
                 //sth happening
            })
        } 
        fetchData();
     }
    )
```

[image: requests screenshot]

Comment: That's what's *supposed* to happen; useEffect without deps gets called every time the component is rendered.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` in order to prepare the data to be fetched. And after the data has been acquired you can update the state of the component.

Comment: UPDATE: useEffect had needed to get a parameter an empty array:
useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchData=async()=>{
           await fetch('https://my-get-request-url')
          .then(stats => stats.json())
          .then(data => {
                 //sth happening
            })
        } 
        fetchData();
     },[]
    )

Answer (score 1):

You should add param which will listen their changes.

```
useEffect(()=>{
   const fetchData=async()=>{
      await fetch('https://my-get-request-url')
      .then(stats => stats.json())
      .then(data => {
             //sth happening
      })
   } 
   fetchData();
}, []) // empty is like one request, you can add there is params and if their change, then useEffect run again
```